# How to avoid spark job workload bias problem

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, database-performance

I have a problem in terms of spark job workload bias.

**Env setting**

Cluster has 5 nodes, one master and 5 workers (below `10.200.0.94 ~ 10.200.0.98`).

Each node has 40 cores (with hyberthreading) and 256g memory.

**Spark job setting**

- num-executors 5
- executor-cores 5
- driver-memory 16g
- executor-memory 20g

The job is to calculate anomaly records among millions of records.

Here is job history after running the job after nearly 2 ~ 3 hours.

[image: overview-spark-job-setting]

As we can see, basically there are 6 stages, most of the time falls into the stage 3, 4 and 5.

Let's dive into stage 3 (stage 4 and 5 have similar results):

[image: dive_into_stage_3]

It's apparently that certain tasks takes much more time than other nodes, such as tasks attached with node having the private ip `10.200.0.96`.

The GC time seems reasonable.

Let's then dive into the executor view:

[image: executor_view]

Node 96 and 98 takes much more task time than other nodes.

It should be noted that I haven't used any `repartition` action.

Can someone give some hints about this ? How can I avoid this kind of computation bias in Spark job ? Is there any common routines to follow ?

Answer (score 0):

have you created pipeline, which are depended one of them, also are you using checkpoint?

Comment: Thanks the reply! No, this is a single app. Yes, I am using checkpoint, but this is actually just pure sql operations, from my perspective, it's not the main cause.